# How can I return a valid JSON response with React-Router and an Express backend?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a setup similar to the one in this [tutorial](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3). How can I render JSON alone (no HTML) without having to specify the port number for the route specified in `index.js`? Within my own setup, I can view JSON by visiting https://socialmaya.com/u/real but can't get an actual JSON response unless I visit http://socialmaya.com:5000/actors/real, which is what's being called by React.

Here is my [code](https://github.com/ethanwilkins/council) which is an attempt to implement an ActivityPub API for a social network built using the MERN stack. My Nginx configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/ethanwilkins/council/blob/master/bin/nginx/node).

Comment: I guess you want to render the data of that json. I'm I right? If that is what you want you need to do a petition to that route with axios, ajax, fetch or something like this and it will return the json data.

Comment: I need to render the JSON itself without any HTML whatsoever encapsulating it. You can see the difference in what I mean if you click to View Page Source for https://socialmaya.com/u/real and http://socialmaya.com:5000/actors/real.

Comment: So I need to render the JSON as plaintext essentially (without having to specify a port number for the backend) but it seems like this might be impossible if I'm using React-Router at all in my project.

Comment: I mean, the content of both webs are the same, only thing changing is the font.

Comment: I think that Mastodon or any other social network using ActivityPub needs to receive the response as valid or pure JSON. As far as I know, if the JSON is being rendered through a React component instead of being returned in a plaintext response, other servers or machines won't be able to read the data successfully.

Comment: When I create a user on my server, I should be able to search for and follow them on Mastodon, which there's a tutorial for here using Express: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/11/decentralizing-social-interactions-with-activitypub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the URL before passing it upstream within Nginx solved my problem:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/u/(.*)$ /actors/$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't require adding an Nginx rewrite for every route I define with Express that I want to be able to access without specifying a port number, that returns valid JSON, and is able to be reached by the browser or something like curl?