# Can React-Router point directly to a route defined with Express instead of rendering a component?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, react-router

How I can use React-Router to point directly to a route defined with Express on the backend instead of rendering a component? I want to return valid JSON with no HTML included in the response.

Answer (score 1):

React-Router only handles routing on the React frontend.

There is no way for React-Router to point to an Express Route on the back end.

A React component would have to use that API endpoint.

Why not just hit the endpoint manually.

Comment: I need to be able to reach the route defined in Express without specifying a port number. Here's my other question regarding the issue I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160329/how-can-i-return-a-valid-json-response-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend

Comment: I'm trying to implement an ActivityPub API for a social network built with the MERN stack.    So when I search for the user created on my server in Mastodon, they need to receive a valid JSON response with no HTML in order for their server to be able to read it.

Comment: Is there any way to return a plaintext response with React, containing no HTML at all and only JSON?

Comment: Adding a rewrite in my nginx config is what solved my issue.