# Is there any way to return a plaintext response with React, containing no HTML at all?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, react-router

I need to be able to return a valid JSON response with no HTML wrapping it all. I can accomplish this by specifying a port number pointing directly to my Express backend but need to be able to return pure JSON without having to specify a port number in production. Is there any way to do this if you're using React/React-Router and Express together?

This setup uses a proxy pass to work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```

Current output: https://socialmaya.com/u/real (1)

Desired output: http://socialmaya.com:5000/actors/real (2)

So I need the output of 1 to be the exact same as 2, ensuring that another server can read it. If you click to View Page Source for both, you can see that the output is not the same.

Comment: For reference, I've asked two other questions related to this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160329/how-can-i-return-a-valid-json-response-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend?noredirect=1#comment108202215_61160329
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162675/can-react-router-point-directly-to-a-route-defined-with-express-instead-of-rende

Comment: It seems to me that it's the URI `/u/real` vs `/actors/real` that introduces the JSON vs HTML? It has nothing to do with `https` vs port 5000.

Comment: That's correct. The reason that I'm only able to access `/actors/real` via port 5000 is that Express is listening on that port. If I attempt to access that URI via `https` and without specifying a port number, React/React-Router renders a 404 page. I'm not sure but it seems like React-Router is blocking any access to Express routes unless they're being called within a component.

Comment: So is your question, how to rewrite `/u/real` to `/actors/real` before passing it upstream? Try `rewrite ^/u/(.*)$ /actors/$1 last;`

Comment: This worked, thank you! Is there another way of doing this? This means having to write a rewrite in Nginx for every single route I define with Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Richard Smith, rewriting the URL before passing it upstream within Nginx solved my problem:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/u/(.*)$ /actors/$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't require adding an Nginx rewrite for every route I define with Express that I want to be able to access without specifying a port number, that returns valid JSON, and is able to be reached by the browser or something like curl?